# How to make the field values of a SQL table to be the keys of JSON object in SQL?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I have been trying to get a JSON object from my DB in the format that I wanted it so I ran the following sql query:

```
SELECT PROJECTS.key_code AS CODE, PROJECTS.name AS Name,
         PROJECTS.date AS Date, PROJECTS.descr AS Description
         FROM PROJECTS LEFT JOIN ACCESS
         ON PROJECTS.key_code = ACCESS.key_code
         WHERE ACCESS.Ukey_code = '5d8hd5' FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

and the result of the query as follow:

```
{
  "Code": "h5P93G",
  "Name": "Project1 test name",
  "Date": "2017-09-03",
  "Description": "This is a test description 1"
 },
  "Code": "KYJ482",
  "Name": "Project2 test name",
  "Date": "2018-10-25",
  "Description": "This is a test description 2"
}
```

but actually what I want is different. The JSON object should look like:

```
{
  "h5P93G": {
          "Name": "Project1 test name",
          "Date": "2017-09-03",
          "Description": "This is a test description 1"
        },
  "KYJ482": {
          "Name": "Project2 test name",
          "Date": "2018-10-25",
          "Description": "This is a test description 2"
        },
}
```

So, how I could get this JSON object?

Comment: You might have to do this transformation outside of SQL server or through stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot really create JSON with variable key names with [`select ... for json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

However, if you don't mind using variables and you're using SQL Server 2017 (otherwise you cannot use dynamic keys for [`json-modify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)), you can do it like this:

```
declare @a nvarchar(max) = '{}'

select
    @a = json_modify(
        @a,
        concat('$."', p.key_code, '"'), /*This line fixed by @Zhorov*/
        json_query((select p.name, p.[date], p.descr for json path, without_array_wrapper))
    )
from projects as p

select @a
```

[<kbd>db fiddle demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51993/3)

If you're using earlier editions of SQL Server, you can just aggregate it with any aggregation method you can find (I've used [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) just for simplicity here):

```
select
    concat('{', string_agg(
        concat('"',p.key_code,'":',p.data),
        ','
    ), '}')
from (
    select
        p.key_code,
        (select p.name, p.[date], p.descr for json path, without_array_wrapper) as data
    from projects as p
) as p
```

[<kbd>db fiddle demo</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7899e4f48d6dfdb38d0dd1b698edfc15)

You might also consider using [`string_escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to prevent errors in case your keys can contain special characters:

```
select
    ...
        concat('"',string_escape(p.key_code,'json'),'":',p.data),
        ','
    ...
```

[<kbd>db fiddle demo</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=488c7f6102fde63fe09d85e4328c77f9)

Comment: Thanks @Roman 
The second solution using the `string_agg` worked for me, but the first one didn't work (I'm using sql server 2017) it threw the following error message:

`Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 3
JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '2' is found at position 2`

Comment: @SalemWafi can you create a db fiddle with your example?

Comment: I was trying to actually, but sqlfiddle.com is down and db-fiddle.com doesn't support MS SQL Databases. 
However, I have the script on db-fiddle website so you can test it at whatever platform that you like which supports MS SQL. 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdYGDDRV9hQPi8x6jkFCX5/1

Comment: Arr you sure sqlfiddle example and the one you trying on your local server are the same?

Comment: Nope actually they are not exactly the same, I just mimicked the schema in sql fiddle and I got the same error there too. Here is the example of it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51993/2

Comment: @RomanPekar You need to escape the `path` to correct this `Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 3 JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '2' is found at position 2` error in your first solution. Change `concat('$.', p.key_code)` to `concat('$."', p.key_code, '"')`. It's a good answer, +1.

Comment: Thanks @Zhorov !! Your edit fixed the issue, here is a fixed fiddle example: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51993/3